# What does android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity extend?

Tags: android, android-studio, inheritance

The webpage with the following address states that the class FragmentActivity extends the class Activity:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

However, when I bring up the documentation for the android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity class within Android Studio, it states that FragmentActivity extends android.support.v4.app.BaseFragementActivityHoneycomb.

What is the reason for the discrepancy and which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes up to `BaseFragmentActivityDonut`. These base fragments are just an implementation detail of `FragmentActivity` and should not concern you at all. In the library I use, `FragmentActivity` directly extends `BaseFragmentActivityJB`. In the future there might be something like `BaseFragmentActivityM` or some compatibility layer for even newer platforms.

For your programming just assume it extends `Activity` only, like the documentation states.